# Unique values per time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table `trips` , I have two columns: `created_at` and `user_id`

My goal is to count unique `user_id`s per month with a query in postgres.  So far, I have written this - but it returns an error

```
SELECT user_id, 
       to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') as t COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
      FROM trips) group by t;
```

How should I change this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is much simpler than that:

```
SELECT to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM trips
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```